# Why is Venom called Venom in Spider-Man 3 and how does the symbiote come to Earth?

Tags: marvel, venom, spider-man-3

Why is Venom called Venom in *Spider-Man 3* (2007), when no one calls him that but the credits? And how does the symbiote come to Earth, because there is no ship?

Comment: You seriously ask why Venom is called Venom? But you do know that the movies is based on the comics, right - so it might derive from the comics? In movie credits also a lot of side characters and extras are sometimes given names as well although they are never mentioned in the movie, and they sometimes do not even have an origin in a book or comic or elsewhere...

Answer (score 6):

He's called Venom in the credits because he's based off of the symbiote of that name in the comics, [the name coined by Eddie Brock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venom_(character)#:%7E:text=Brock%20took%20on%20the%20name,as%20well%20as%20its%20hosts.).

[image: Image of Brock giving his name, and why]

> Brock took on the name Venom in reference to the sensationalistic material he was forced to traffic in following his fall from grace.

As you note, that name is not used within the film, with the symbiote being referred to as the symbiote.

And the symbiote came down on a meteorite that landed near Peter.

### Scene where the symbiote arrives

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly pointed out, no one in *Spider-Man 3* refers to either the alien symbiote on its own, or the union of the symbiote and Eddie Brock, as 'Venom,' so that version of the character doesn't appear to have that name in-universe.

The filmmakers refer to him as 'Venom' because the character is based on an [existing character](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Venom_(Symbiote)_(Earth-616)) in the Spider-Man comics, which made its first appearance as the alien symbiote in *[Marvel Super Heroes Secret Wars #8](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Super_Heroes_Secret_Wars_Vol_1_8)* (December, 1984). However it wasn't known by the name 'Venom' until *[Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 1 #300](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_300)* (May, 1988), when it was bonded with the comicbook version of [Eddie Brock](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Edward_Brock_(Earth-616)). Eddie himself came up with the name in-universe, in *[Web of Spider-Man Annual #8](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Web_of_Spider-Man_Annual_Vol_1_8)* (June, 1992).

> SAM RAIMI: **Marvel comicbooks always had a great bunch of villains to choose from in the Spider-Man universe.** So many great Marvel artists and writers had developed these wonderful characters and written stories and had drawn great images to go along with them that **it was a very easy task to pick those wonderful tales and images that we wanted to make this film based upon.**
>
> KEVIN FEIGE: **A few months after we got the initial story, the idea came about, "let's introduce the symbiote, let's introduce the black suit," and of course that means only one thing: "let's introduce Venom."**
>
> AVI ARAD: **The symbiote is the ultimate story in the comics, and that's Eddie Brock, who becomes Venom.**
>
> GRANT CURTIS: Venom has a very unique origin story. How do we tell that story and do justice to the character who is arguably the most popular Marvel character of all time?
>
> [...]
>
> KEVIN FEIGE: **The symbiote famously first appeared in the *Secret Wars* and the *Spider-Man* comics,** and in the comics, it's really usually seen as a slightly expanding black, oily-type substance.
>
> [...]
>
> LAURA ZISKIN: **Venom is our interpretation of the comicbook, and I think the fans will be happy.**
>
> <sub>*Spider-Man 3* (2007) - "Covered In Black: Creating Venom" DVD featurette</sub>

---

As for how the alien symbiote arrived on Earth in *Spider-Man 3*, it did so encased within a meteor. This is very reminiscent of how another gelatinous alien arrived on Earth in the classic 1958 sci-fi movie, *[The Blob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blob)*, and the older movie may have helped to inspire this scene.

> **A fiery meteor plummets from the sky and smacks down in the forest.** Mary Jane and Peter, wrapped in each other's arms, are oblivious to it. **The glowing orange meteor, embedded in the ground, cracks open. Black tendrils, like living vines, spring out of it and stretch across the ground.** Peter, smiling happily, slides down a thread of webbing with Mary Jane, unaware of the tendrils crawling up a nearby ridge like a huge black spider. Peter revs his moped. With Mary Jane sitting on the pillion seat, the moped starts to move off. The strange black substance crawls speedily up behind it and attaches itself to the rear number plate as the moped rides off down the woodland track.
>
> <sub>*Spider-Man 3* (2007) - DVD Audio Description track</sub>

This depiction of the symbiote's arrival on Earth differs greatly from the comics, and one of the producers on *Spider-Man 3*, Laura Ziskin, offered the following explanation for the filmmakers' decision to go in this direction.

> LAURA ZISKIN: You know, we didn't want to spend a lot of the movie explaining its origins or where it came from, so "it came from outer space." You know, that seemed like that was true to the comics without all the astronaut stuff.
>
> <sub>*Spider-Man 3* (2007) - "Covered In Black: Creating Venom" DVD featurette</sub>